# Swift UITableViewCell Segue To another View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to make a music player and in one view, I have a `UITableView` of playlists and I want when the user taps a cell for it to segue to another `UITableView` that contains a tabled list of the songs in the playlist. When doing this, I get the following error:

> "2017-07-22 23:58:35.479139-0700 FoodTracker[740:118055] ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 1080}>'s
>   window is not equal to 's
>   view's window!"

The name of the project is foodTracker because I built a testing project off of an Apple tutorial project. Also, playlistTable is the tableview with the songs. Not the playlists. Is there any way I can resolve this error?

My code for tableView()  is as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let thePlaylist = playlistArray[indexPath.row].songs
    songsToShow = loadSongs(songs: thePlaylist)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playlistTable") as! playlistTable
    destination.songArr =  songsToShow
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTo", sender: self) 

}
```

Comment: Are the 2 `UITableView`s in the same or different view(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing both? Remove one of these.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTo", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

@JuatANoob I think you are made some basic mistake in your code snippet there is no need to do both code of pushNavigation and performSegue in the same snippet. the both thing in one snippet will make confuse. so there is only one thing you need to do with your code. either `pushNavigation` or either `performSegue`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply comment this line if you don't need segue through storyboard .

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTo", sender: self)
```